# Copy a txt file twice to a different file using bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to cat a file.txt and loop it twice through the whole content and copy it to a new file file_new.txt. The bash command I am using is as follows:

```
for i in {1..3}; do cat file.txt > file_new.txt; done
```

The above command is just giving me the same file contents as file.txt. Hence file_new.txt is also of the same size (1 GB).

Basically, if file.txt is a 1GB file, then I want file_new.txt to be a 2GB file, double the contents of file.txt. Please, can someone help here? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply **apply the redirection to the `for` loop *as a whole***:

```
for i in {1..3}; do cat file.txt; done > file_new.txt
```

The advantage of this over using `>>` (aside from not having to open and close the file multiple times) is that you needn't ensure that a preexisting output file is truncated first.

---

Note that the **generalization** of this approach is to **use a *group command* (`{ ...; ...; }`) to apply redirections to *multiple* commands**; e.g.:

```
$ { echo hi; echo there; } > out.txt; cat out.txt
hi
there
```

---

Given that whole files are being output, the cost of invoking `cat` for each repetition will probably not matter that much, but here's **a robust way to invoke `cat` only *once*:**<sup>[1]</sup>

```
# Create an array of repetitions of filename 'file' as needed.
files=(); for ((i=0; i<3; ++i)); do files[i]='file'; done
# Pass all repetitions *at once* as arguments to `cat`.
cat "${files[@]}" > file_new.txt
```

---

<sup>[1] Note that, hypothetically, you could run into your platform's command-line length limit, as reported by `getconf ARG_MAX` - given that on Linux that limit is `2,097,152` bytes (2MB) that's not likely, though.</sup>

Comment: Just a twist in the command after done..Ahh..Got me a long time to think about it..Thanks!!

Comment: @deep: My pleasure.It's not obvious, but the whole `for` loop is a single, so-called compound command from Bash's perspective, as is the group command, so redirections can be applied to them as a whole.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the append operator, `>>`, instead of `>`.  Then adjust your loop count as needed to get the output size desired.

Comment: `>>` is not necessary if you apply `>` to the `for` loop as a whole, which has the added advantage of not having to ensure beforehand that a preexisting output file is truncated - which is something you should mention with respect to `>>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should adjust your code so it is as follows:

`for i in {1..3}; do cat file.txt >> file_new.txt; done`

The `>>` operator *appends* data to a file rather than writing over it (`>`)

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you can use `>>` to append.  But, you could also just invoke `cat` once and have it read the file 3 times.  For instance:

```
n=3; cat $( yes file.txt | sed ${n}q ) > file_new.txt
```

Note that this solution exhibits a common anti-pattern and fails to properly quote the arguments, which will cause issues if the filename contains whitespace.  See mklement's solution for a more robust solution.

Comment: This approach works with the specific filename at hand, but fails with filenames such as `file 1.txt`.
Use of an unquoted command substitution to expand to a command's arguments is an anti-pattern; please at least warn of its pitfalls.

Comment: @mklement0 You raise a valid concern, but I think the bigger anti-pattern is the use of whitespace in filenames!  I've never thought of it as an 'anti-pattern' before, but I think it matches the definition.

Comment: Using the capabilities provided by a platform - filesystems with support for whitespace and other non-alphanumerics - is not an anti-pattern.
Writing code that doesn't account for these capabilities is.
It is safe to assume that many readers of this post do have to deal with such filenames, irrespective of how they _personally_ feel about it.
It is unfortunate that modern capabilities clash with longstanding features of POSIX-like shells that assumed whitespace-free filenames (but let's not forget unwanted globbing), but if you want to write robust code, you cannot rely on them anymore.

Comment: I whole-heartedly agree that code should be written robustly to allow whitespace in filenames, and that my example here does not.  (I'm not trying to start an argument about whitespace, truly!)  But almost all anti-patterns are an example of using capabilities provided by a system (language, platform, etc.) in a way that is not ideal.  The fact that file systems generally allow whitespace is not an argument against the use of whitespace in filenames being an anti-pattern.

Comment: By that definition (which I agree with) an unquoted command substitution _is_ an anti-pattern: it is not ideal, because it handles only a narrowly defined, non-obvious subset of real-world use cases.
You can apply the same logic to incorporating spaces in your filenames (I disagree), but given how prevalent they are, most people, methinks, consider them "a feature, not a bug".
The point is: without stating all the assumptions you're making, _directly in your answer_, your post can mislead readers to think that unquoted command substitutions are a _generally_ valid way to specify arguments.

Answer (score 0):

if file.txt is a 1GB file,

`cat file.txt > file_new.txt
cat file.txt >> file_new.txt`

The `>` operator will create `file_new.txt`(1GB),
The `>>` operator will append `file_new.txt`(2GB).

`for i in {1..3}; do cat file.txt >> file_new.txt; done`

This command will make `file_new.txt`(3GB),because `for i in {1..3}` will run three times.